# Not able to get value of a tag using beautiful soup

Tags: xml, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Using the python code i am not able to get the value ethernet1/1 from the name tag?, It just returns the value entry

```
<response status="success">
<result>
<hw>
<entry>
<name>ethernet1/1</name>
<duplex>full</duplex>
<type>0</type>
<state>up</state>
<st>1000/full/up</st>
<mac>00:1s:15:22:05:45</mac>
<mode>(autoneg)</mode>
<speed>1000</speed>
<id>16</id>
</entry>


for interface in hwintmarkup.find_all("entry"):
    interfaced={'name':interface.name,
                'duplex':str(interface.duplex.get_text()),
                'state':str(interface.state.get_text()),
                'mac':str(interface.mac.get_text()),
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is a reserved variable to get the current tag name. You'll have to use something like this:

```
interface.find('name')
```